# Add multiple hostnames to .env file for Django

Tags: django

I have created a Django project using Django Cookiecutter with Docker.

So far so good, but I keep getting a 400 error (Bad request).

When I look in the log on Sentry, I can see the message that I need to add the ip address 123.123.123.132 to allowed hosts.

In .env there is a variable `DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS`, which by default contains the domain name that was entered when using Cookiecutter.

Some ways I have tried so far:

```
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=.foo.bar,123.123.123.132
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=.foo.bar 123.123.123.132
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=[.foo.bar,123.123.123.132]
```

What syntax should I use here to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Deleting my previous comment, but have you checked your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` variable in your Django settings file?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/)

You should try

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [".foo.bar" , "123.123.123.132"]
```